# Swift 2: Update UIImage Dictionary with UIImage() var from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift2

I have two ViewControllers. ViewController#1 contains the UIImagePicker and ViewController #2 contains the UIImage dictionary variable with Key. I would like to update the dictionary array with the UIImage variable (var newImage = UIImage() )that I passed from ViewController#1.The array is expecting a string so I tried converting the UIImage array to a string. I also confirmed that the image  No luck.Any ideas?

```
ViewController#1:

  class ViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var testimage = UIImage()

    @IBOutlet weak var beaconOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var beaconTwo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var backImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var majorID2: UITextField!

    @IBAction func pickPhoto(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage pickedimage: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        testimage = pickedimage
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print(images)


    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let planVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PlanagramViewController

        planVC.newImage = testimage


    }


}




ViewController#2:

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  BeaconTest
//
//  Created by Apple on 5/6/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Apple. All rights reserved.
//
// Uses CoreLocation Framework



import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class PlanagramViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView!


    var newImage = UIImage()
    var beaconImages = [51098: UIImage(named: "Plan_P"),21714: UIImage(named: "Plan_M")]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let newvcMajorID = Int(vcMajorID1)
        beaconImages.updateValue(UIImage(named: "Plan_P"), forKey: newvcMajorID!)

        let newvcMajorID2 = Int(vcMajorID2)
        beaconImages.updateValue(UIImage(named: "Plan_M"), forKey: newvcMajorID2!)




    }


}
```

Comment: Not quite sure with what you want to achieve do you want to change  the image already stored in the dictionary for a certain key .

Comment: Yes. I would like to replace the "Plan_P" and "Plan_M" images in the array for the var newImage = UIImage()  that I declared in ViewController #2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do .  Grab (in code)the planogram view controller from ui story board and send the image to new image and than in view controller #  2 simply use that value.

view controller #2

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class PlanagramViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var testimageview: UIImageView!
    var newImage : UIImage?
    var beaconImages = [51098: UIImage(named: "Image"),21714: UIImage(named: "Image")]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        beaconImages.updateValue(newImage, forKey: 51098)


        beaconImages.updateValue(newImage, forKey: 21714)

        imageview.image = beaconImages[21714]!
        testimageview.image = beaconImages[51098]!




    }


}
```

view controller #1
simply change the below function and remove everything from the prepare for segue method .

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage pickedimage: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        testimage = pickedimage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        images.append(testimage)
           let        planVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("planagram") as? PlanagramViewController
     planVC?.newImage = testimage
        self.presentViewController((planVC)!
            , animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```